# How to see what the equal interval breaks are in order to add them to the CartoDB Legend

Tags: carto

I am using median income for Oakland, CA, where each polygon represents a block group with a number associated with it for its median income. I've displayed the data as a choropleth and chosen equal interval for the data. How can I see what those intervals are in order to add them to the legend?

Answer (score 1):

Check the CartoCSS in the "Map View".

[image]

It will look something like this:

```
/** choropleth visualization */

#bushwick_pluto14v1{
  polygon-fill: #F1EEF6;
  polygon-opacity: 0.8;
  line-color: #FFF;
  line-width: 0.3;
  line-opacity: 0.7;
}
#bushwick_pluto14v1 [ far_diff <= 4] {
   polygon-fill: #980043;
}
#bushwick_pluto14v1 [ far_diff <= 2] {
   polygon-fill: #DD1C77;
}
#bushwick_pluto14v1 [ far_diff <= 1.5] {
   polygon-fill: #DF65B0;
}
#bushwick_pluto14v1 [ far_diff <= 1] {
   polygon-fill: #D7B5D8;
}
#bushwick_pluto14v1 [ far_diff <= 0.5] {
   polygon-fill: #F1EEF6;
}
```

The code inside of the square brackets, ie: `[far_diff <=1.5]` will show you what the buckets are. In the code above from top down they are roughly 4 - 2.1, 2 - 1.6, 1.5 - 1.1, 1 - 0.6 and 0.5 - 0.